# How to modify MVCHtmlString returned by Html.Partial("PartialViewName")

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one Partial View in which there is one anchor tag. Once I load partial view using Html.Partial(), I want to delete that anchor tag based on condition. Like:

```
@{
   var html = Html.Partial("PartialView");
   if(true)
   {
      // Delete anchor tag from MVCHtmlString.
   }
}
```

**Note:** I want to delete anchor tag and then want to render remained html on page. I am aware of all of those tricks of ViewBag, Jquery/Javascript. I just want to know how I can do this way? How I can get that element and how I can remove that and render remained html?

Comment: Why not put that condition within the partial itself (or alternatively use javascript to delete the element based on your condition)

Comment: I can't put condition in partial view as being used at many place to it would b e good if I can do it this way. Else I know how to do it from jquery. :)

Comment: Yes you can. Have your partial accept a model and pass a parameter in it. Do not provide the model in places where you want to keep the existing behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure what you think that has to do with it. You could just pass a model to the partial (or use `ViewBag`) and use that as your conditional check. To do what you want would involve creating you own extension method and using a html parser (e.g. HtmlAgilityPack). Not worth the effort

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, you can handle this in your partial view itself, rather than manipulating MvcHtmlString. If your concern is your partial view being used in many places, you could use `ViewBag` like this:

In your current `ActionMethod`:

```
ViewBag.HideAnchor = true;
```

In your Partial View:

```
// first condition is true for all the other places it is being used
@if (ViewBag.HideAnchor == null || !ViewBag.HideAnchor)
{
    // your anchor
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't get the exact question. I have every options you folks suggesting. I want to do it the way I have specified in my question. Anyway thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @PriyankSheth No, I got your question. You said *"I can't put condition in partial view as being used at many place"*. So I'm saying it doesn't matter if it used in many places, as you can check for null. If you insist on manipluating MVCHTMLString you can use [Html Agility Pack - remove](http://html-agility-pack.net/remove). This is good [article](https://world.episerver.com/blogs/Anders-Hattestad/Dates/2014/2/How-to-get-html-from-a-view-and-change-the-content-in-MVC/) on the subject